# python - populate generator on class init or defer?

Tags: python, class, yield

I've got a django app that, at a very pseudo-codey level, does something like this:

```
class SerialisedContentItem():

    def __init__(self, item),
        self.__output = self.__jsonify(item)

    def fetch_output(self):
        return self.__output

    def __jsonify(self, item):
        serialized = do_a_bunch_of_serialisey_stuff()
        return json.dumps(serialized)
```

So basically - as soon as the class is instantiated, it:

- runs an internal function to generate an output string of JSON
- stores it in an internal variable
- exposes a public function that can be
  called later to retrieve the JSON

It's then being used to generate a page something like this:

```
for item in page.items:
    json_item = SerialisedContentItem(item)
    yield json_item.fetch_output()
```

This, to me, seems a bit pointless. And it's also causing issues with some business logic changes we need to make.

What I'd prefer to do is defer the calling of the "jsonify" function until I actually want it. Roughly speaking, changing the above to:

```
class SerialisedContentItem():

    def __init__(self, item),
        self.__item = item

    def fetch_output(self):
        return self.__jsonify(self.__item):
```

This seems simpler, and mucks with my logic slightly less.

But: is there a downside I'm not seeing? Is my change less performant, or not a good way of doing things?

Comment: The only downside I can think of, is when you need the jsonified string quite often, which means multiple jsonification, resulting in higher load on the system. Then it does makes sense to store it.

Comment: It's only being used once, via `yield`. Which is really what's prompted my question: according to my (poor) understanding of `yield`, using it here makes sense: I only need to iterate page items once, so do so in a way that minimises the memory footprint. But the bulk of the work isn't currently being done in the `yield` function, it's being done on the line above it when the class is instantiated, making `yield` a bit pointless. Or am I misunderstanding how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you only call `fetch_output` once per item, there's no performance hit (there would be one, obviously, if you called `fetch_output` twice on the same `SerializedContentItem` instance). And not doing useless operations is usually a good thing too (you don't expect `open("/path/to/some/file.ext")` to read the file's content, do you ?)

The only caveat is that, with the original version, if `item` is mutated between the initialization of `SerializedContentItem` and the call to `fetch_output`, the change won't be reflected in the json output (since it's created right at initialisation time), while with your "lazy" version those changes WILL reflect in the json. Whether this is a no-go, a potential issue or actually just what you want depends on the context, so only you can tell.

EDIT:

> what's prompted my question: according to my (poor) understanding of yield, using it here makes sense: I only need to iterate page items once, so do so in a way that minimises the memory footprint. But the bulk of the work isn't currently being done in the yield function, it's being done on the line above it when the class is instantiated, making yield a bit pointless. Or am I misunderstanding how it works?

I'm afraid you are indeed misunderstanding `yield`. Defering the json seralization until the `yield json_item.fetch_output()` will change **nothing** (nada, zero, zilch, shunya) to memory comsuption wrt/ the original version.

`yield` is not a function, it's a keyword. What it does is to turn the function containing it into a "generator function" - a function that returns a generator (a lazy iterator) object, that you can then iterate over. It will not change anything to the memory used to jsonify an item, and whether this jsonification happens "on the same line" as the `yield` keyword or not is totally irrelevant.

What a generator brings you (wrt/ memory use) is that you don't have to create a whole list of contents at once, ie:

```
def eager():
   result = []
   for i in range(1000):
       result.append("foo {}\n".format(i))
   return result

with open("file.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for item in eager():
        outfile.write(item)
```

This FIRST creates a 1000 items long list in memory, then iterate over it.

vs

```
def lazy():
   result = []
   for i in range(1000):
       yield "foo {}\n".format(i)

with open("file.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for item in lazy():
        outfile.write(item)
```

this lazily generates string after string on each iteration, so you don't end up with a 1000 items list in memory - BUT you still generated 1000 strings, each of them using the same amount of space as with the first solution. The difference is that since (in this example) you don't keep any reference on those strings they can be garbage collected on each iteration, while storing them in a list prevent them from being collected until there' no more reference on the list itself.

Comment: Well, exactly. There are now cases where I might not want to return a jsonified item, so jsonifying it on init() is unnecessary overhead. I was concerned that there's some aspect of the way it's currently being done that makes it work better with `yield`, but it looks so far like that's not the case. Thanks :)